# c# how to pause between 2 function calls without stopping main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

c# how to pause between 2 function calls without stopping main thread

```
Foo();
Foo(); // i want this to run after 2 min without stopping main thread


Function Foo()
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: use a timer, or a seperate thread for both and thread.sleep

Comment: see this, an explanation why timer is efficient than stopping the thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391621/compare-using-thread-sleep-and-timer-for-delayed-execution

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { foo(); })
    .ContinueWith(t => Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000))
    .ContinueWith(t => { Foo() });
```

Comment: This will waste a thread from pool to just sleep on it for 2 minutes(!). Pool is something limited and it could execute a lot of work on that thread, instead of being busy doing nothing

Answer (score 2):

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo)
                .ContinueWith(t => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)))
                .ContinueWith(t => Foo());
```

**Please, do not sleep on thread pool. Never**

"There are only a limited number of threads in the thread pool; thread pools are designed to efficiently execute a large number of short tasks. They rely on each task finishing quickly, so that the thread can return to the pool and be used for the next task."
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305814/sleeping-in-a-pooled-c-sharp-thread)

**Why `Delay`? It uses `DelayPromise` internally with a `Timer`**, it's efficient, way more efficient

Comment: and another +1 for the same reason. it is easy to overlook that :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `Timer`:

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 120000;
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    Foo();
    timer.Stop();
}
timer.Start();
```

Comment: this is not compiling - how do you init the Timer?

Answer (score 1):

Try spawning a new thread, like so:

```
new Thread(() => 
    {
         Foo();
         Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
         Foo();
    }).Start();
```

Comment: If the OP is using .NET 4.0 or later, it's better to use `Task`.

Comment: In such a simple case, I would back the claim that `Task` is better with reasons.

Comment: This is actually better than using Task+Sleep, this solution uses dedicated thread and does not steal threads from pool for making important stuff like sleeping...But, Task+Delay is way more easier

Comment: @taras.roshko that's why I ask. I see too often that Task is used without rethinking the context or to execute long running actions

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic agree. It's always better to know the internals

Comment: @taras.roshko I would say that you should never use Thread.Sleep to pause for 2 minutes. Not in the first or the second case. What if you want to cancel thread execution? Should the user wait for 2 minutes to expire the wait time? A better solution is to use an EventWaitHandle or some other wait mechanism that you can cancel at any time.

Comment: @ZoranCausev I completely agree with you, nevertheless I believe that main part of the question was not about which delay method should be used in this case (also that 2 minutes was just an example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public void Foo()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo();

        // Create a timer with a two minutes interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(120000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Foo());

        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Foo();
    }
}
```

The code has not been tested.

Comment: Task.Delay also uses timer internally

Answer (score 0):

```
var testtask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        Foo();
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0,0,20));
        Foo();
    });
```